# how to access page load methods in other methods of a same class in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a method in page load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        IEnumerable<int> Ids = GetIds();

    }
}
public IEnumerable<int> GetIds()
{
    IEnumerable<int> Ids;
    using ()
    {
        //query to get data from back end
    }
    return Ids;
}
```

how can i use page load **Ids** List in other method of a same class?is it possible?

actually i am trying to load all the data of back end at once on page load and then use them in different methods of a same class.

Comment: Why not store them in a field of the class?

Comment: @Harshit check my answer below.

Comment: @Abi - The name is class field, not global variable. It is accessible from inside the same class.

Comment: Why do you do that in `Page_Load`? Do that where you need it, for example in a button-click event handler method. It will be null on every postback anyway, not sure if that's desired.

Comment: @TimSchmelter , I have a method in that class which has a foreach and it validates data from backend .so i am thinking like rather than sending it back and forth .load that on page load and use it in the method.the fetched data is static it wont change.

Comment: Sending back and forth from where to where? When the method is called?

Comment: actually its fetching not sending from db.method has around 100 rows so for each row it checks is the list.so i think loading them at page load is good option.

Answer (score 2):

Declare it as global variable in class.

```
IEnumerable<int> Ids;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                 Ids = GetIds();

             }
    }
 public IEnumerable<int> GetIds()
   {
        IEnumerable<int> IdsToReturn;
        using ()
        {
               //Here you can get Ids;  
               //query to get data from back end
        }
        return IdsToReturn;
    }
```

Comment: Well, this would be null on every postback. Instead i'd recommend to load it only where you need it not always in page_load. If the user clicks f.e. on a button you should load it in the button-click event handler method.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply use a variable to store the IDs value, it will not be persisted and will be null in the next postback.

You can persist data across postbacks using ViewState, for example:

```
private List<int> IDs
{
    get{ return (List<int>)ViewState["IDs"]; }
    set{ ViewState["IDs"] = value; }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        IDs = GetIds();
        //IDs will be available in the next postbacks
    }
}
```